# How to compare two folders that has names as the date. in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have made backup folder as per the date on which backup is taken. Now want  to delete the backup that is more than 20 days old.  Don't know how to initiate this ? Please guide using batch programming

Answer (score 0):

To delete files older than 20 days you can do this

```
forfiles -p "C:\yourbackupfolder" -s -m *.* -d 20 -c "cmd /c del @file"
```